# How to make a unit test in meteor that adds a document to a collection? Mocking userId

Tags: unit-testing, meteor, mocha.js

Thank you for your help-

**I'd like to know if my app successfully adds a document to the database using a unit test in Meteor.** I'm using practicalmeteor:mocha and chai. The issue I'm running into is that I don't know how to mock a this.userId, it keeps telling me I'm not logged in.

```js
it('inserts the draft agenda document into the collection', function() {
      // TODO: mock document to insert into collection     
      // TODO: mock userId and Agenda.insert      
      this.userId = "Not an empty string";
      console.log("before spec, changing this.userId: " + this.userId) //is "Not an empty string"

      Meteor.call('createAgenda', mockAgenda, function(res) {
          console.log("callback with response: " + res); //You're not logged-in. [not-logged-in]        
          console.log("this.userId: " + this.userId) //is undefined
        }
}
```

- see https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#DDPCommon-MethodInvocation-userId for more info on user id
- test runner fails to import files in client directory
- `MochaRunner.runServerTests: failures: 1` when meteor methods are called
- I have to call the server side meteor methods that have been declared in the testing context as if I am on the client, but **I can't import the client files or operate as if I'm a client**
- `MochaRunner.runServerTests: Starting server side tests with run id R7ocZh3Qva3rExTL9` runs basically every time
- This seems useful but hasn't worked for me yet https://forums.meteor.com/t/testing-methods-which-use-this-userid/2292/8

Thank you for your help, any code examples would be great.

Answer (score 3):

### Remarks

I wanted to post a comment but do not have enough reputation. So here are some remarks. Since you are testing on the server, you can call a Meteor method without a callback. This will result in a synchronous execution and simplify your test. Otherwise you will have to let the test know it is finished by calling the **done** function in your callback, see [mocha docs](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code).

### Using [mdg:validated-method](https://github.com/meteor/validated-method)

You can call a valited method and provide the context in which they execute using the **_execute** function. Below is an example taken from the [todos sample project](https://github.com/meteor/todos). For more examples you can take a look at their [Lists](https://github.com/meteor/todos/blob/master/imports/api/lists/lists.tests.js) and [Todos](https://github.com/meteor/todos/blob/master/imports/api/todos/todos.tests.js) tests.

```js
it('makes a list private and updates the todos', function() {
  // Check initial state is public
  assert.isFalse(Lists.findOne(listId).isPrivate());

  // Set up method arguments and context
  const methodInvocation = {
    userId
  };
  const args = {
    listId
  };

  // Making the list private adds userId to the todo
  makePrivate._execute(methodInvocation, args);
  assertListAndTodoArePrivate();

  // Making the list public removes it
  makePublic._execute(methodInvocation, args);
  assert.isUndefined(Todos.findOne(todoId).userId);
  assert.isTrue(Todos.findOne(todoId).editableBy(userId));
});
```

### Using standard methods

Another possiblity would be to bind the standard **call** function to the correct context. Note that this is just a thought and not tested.

```js
var methodInvocation = {
  userId: "some user id"
};

Meteor.call.bind(methodInvocation)('createAgenda', mockAgenda);
```